# Dockerizing Rails Application ActiveRecord::NoEnvironmentInSchemaError while running migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am dockerizing my rails application. I usually run the following command to initialize my database`bundle exec rake db:reset db:migrate db:seed`. This command applies to both test database and development. After dockerizing my application, running this command using `docker-composer` like this(`docker-compose run  web bundle exec rake db:reset db:migrate db:seed`) is resulting with this error:

```
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::NoEnvironmentInSchemaError:

Environment data not found in the schema. To resolve this issue, run:

        bin/rails db:environment:set RAILS_ENV=development

/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1135:in `last_stored_environment'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:58:in `check_protected_environments!'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:13:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bugsnag-6.8.0/lib/bugsnag/integrations/rake.rb:18:in `execute_with_bugsnag'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-12.3.3/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/bundle:30:in `block in <main>'
/usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:reset => db:drop => db:check_protected_environments
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Now interestingly, when I run the migrations using this command `docker-compose run web bundle exec rake db:create db:migrate` it worked and I think because this command it only affects the development database. Anyone could help me with managing environments of a rails app using docker? I need to drop the database and run that command on both test and development database.

My dockerfile is simple and it looks like this:

```
FROM ruby:2.5.3

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs

RUN mkdir /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp

COPY Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /myapp/Gemfile.lock

RUN bundle install

COPY . /myapp
```

my docker compose is also simple:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:12.2-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: 'db_dev'
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: "trust"
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

My .env is empty though

Comment: Can you please add your `Dockerfile`, `docker-compose.yml` and your `.env` ?

Comment: I did. The bottom line of this is the `POSTGRES_DB` key I guess

Comment: Ok, so what you have is the `RAILS_ENV` is set the development. First time you run this project, you'll need to create the database and migrate it using `docker-compose run web rake db:setup` and this will create your database. Next run can be done via `docker-compose up`; Now, if you want to use `production`, you'll need to add the `env` key to your `web` config and set the RAILS_ENV there

Comment: Also, there's an error in your compose file. 1- no need to use `-b 0.0.0.0`; 2- your rails port is on 3000 while your `web.ports` is on 3001;

Comment: @RocKhalil:
I tried the env being sat like this: still the same error
`docker-compose run  -e "RAILS_ENV=development" web bundle exec rake db:setup`

Comment: @RocKhalil I don't think the ports are relevant for the migration. I was just playing around with them coz I have other projects running on 3000

Comment: Yes I know they are not relevant, but I'm just pointing out this error :-p However, for the migration, maybe try destroying your images using `docker image rmi` and rebuild them from scratch. Maybe there was an error when building the `pg` image and its volume. (delete the volume too using `docker volume rmi`)

Comment: @RocKhalil:
removed, rebuilt, rerun the migration. same results still.